# Объясните как Visual Studio работает с базами данных

Tags: база-данных, visual-studio, sql-server

У меня есть проект в `Visual Studio` на `c#`, `web-приложение asp.net`.
По дефолту в проекте была создана локальная база данных. Обозреватель серверов говорит, что источником данных является `Microsoft SQL Server`. `Visual Studio` работает только с `Microsoft SQL Server` или при желании можно подключиться к другой субд? Объясните пожалуйста как все это работает, покоя мне не дает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/176017/) довольно доходчево рассказано, как работать с БД, можете почитать всю серию статей, очень полезно будет.

[Тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/215999/) посмотрите про использование СУБД PostgreSQL

Вообще, можно подключить любую СУБД к ASP.NET, ищите примеры с помощью гугла, он ваш друг и помощник